# Estoy teniendo este error cuando en mi API en ejecución

Tags: javascript, api

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6932:00000007E3D0C910] 63877717 ms: Mark-sweep 1422.1 (1523.2) -> 1421.9 (1484.7) MB, 1051.4 / 0.0 ms last resort GC in old space requested
[6932:00000007E3D0C910] 63879259 ms: Mark-sweep 1421.9 (1484.7) -> 1421.9  (1481.7) MB, 1541.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


 <--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000DC9F925879 <JSObject>
1: doneHandler [C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\globalsys-APP\gsys\api-gsys\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:~647] [pc=00000050E3884601](this=0000000857DE4FC1 <Request map = 000002CA5F7A1E69>,rowCount=1,more=0000001FE7702371 <true>)
2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
3: emitThree(aka emitThree) [events.js:~134] [pc=00000050E38E3D7B](this=0000001FE77022D1 <undefined>,handler=0000000...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedDoubleArray
 5: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 6:   v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex
 7: 00000050E36043C1
```

**Este es mi package.json**

```
    {
    "name": "api-gsys",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "jonathanludena ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mssql": "^4.1.0",
    "tedious": "^2.2.4"
    }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrias ponernos en contexto? ¿Que estas intentando hacer?

Comment: Es API que realiza Transacciones SQL a una base SQL Server mediante mssql package en NPM y al parecer cada cierto tiempo tiene este error que al parecer trata de una sobrecarga en memoria, que es lo que entiendo, pero quiero saber si alguien le ha pasado o ha podido corregir este problema.

Front-end - API (express-mssql) - DB (Sql Server 2008 R2)